# Why is Bootstrap Dropdown not working after activating the Tooltips?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, nrwl-nx

When I am activating all tooltips the dropdown toggle is not longer working. Is there another way to activate the tooltip?

**Activating Tooltips**

```
    private elementRef: ElementRef = inject(ElementRef);

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        const tooltipTriggerList = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]');
        [...tooltipTriggerList].forEach(el => {
            new bootstrap.Tooltip(el);
        });
        // [...tooltipTriggerList].map(el => new bootstrap.Tooltip(el, { animation: true }));
    }
```

**CSS and JavaScript imports**

```
                "styles": [
                    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                    "./node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css",
                    "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
                    "./apps/vulcan/src/theme.scss",
                    "./apps/vulcan/src/styles.scss"
                ],
                "scripts": [
                    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                ]
```

**NX Report**

```
>  NX   Report complete - copy this into the issue template

   Node   : 18.13.0
   OS     : win32-x64
   npm    : 9.6.6
   
   nx (global)        : 17.1.1
   nx                 : 17.1.3
   @nx/js             : 17.1.3
   @nx/jest           : 17.1.3
   @nx/linter         : 17.1.3
   @nx/eslint         : 17.1.3
   @nx/workspace      : 17.1.3
   @nx/angular        : 17.1.3
   @nx/cypress        : 17.1.3
   @nx/devkit         : 17.1.3
   @nx/eslint-plugin  : 17.1.3
   @nrwl/tao          : 17.1.3
   @nx/web            : 17.1.3
   @nx/webpack        : 17.1.3
   typescript         : 5.2.2
   ---------------------------------------
   Community plugins:
   @progress/kendo-angular-buttons      : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs   : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-dialog       : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns    : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-excel-export : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-grid         : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-icons        : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-indicators   : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-inputs       : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-l10n         : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-label        : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-layout       : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-listview     : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-navigation   : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-notification : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-scheduler    : 14.1.0
   @progress/kendo-angular-tooltip      : 14.1.0
```

**Git Repo without nx but the same problem**

https://github.com/mkeuschn/angular-bootstrap-app.git

**Could be opened with the Stackblitz IDE**

[https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/mkeuschn/angular-bootstrap-app](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/mkeuschn/angular-bootstrap-app)

Comment: Do you get errors in the browser console?

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting no errors